# Build Error Using Static Site Generator (Gatsby) and Microsoft Graph Toolkit

Tags: gatsby, microsoft-graph-toolkit

I'm trying to use the Microsoft Graph Toolkit in a static site generator (Gatsby) but running into an erro doing a server side build. The original error is on:

`const policy = window.trustedTypes`

in the `lit-html` package. I can remove this using `onCreateWebpackConfig` in gatsby-node.js. If I do, a get the next error, on `lit-element`. Eventually, I got as far as removing `microsoft` using the, following gatsby-node.js:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
                test: /lit-html/,
                use: loaders.null(),
            },
            {
                test: /lit-element/,
                use: loaders.null(),
            },
            {
                test: /microsoft/,
                use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
      })
    }
  }
```

Unfortunately, now I'm just stuck with:

```
failed Building static HTML for pages - 3.769s
error Building static HTML failed for path "/404/"


  Error: Minified React error #130; visit https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html?invariant=130&args[]=undefined&args[]= for the full message or use the non-minified dev environment for full errors and 
  additional helpful warnings.

  - react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:48 a.b.render
    [ComplianceForms-Web]/[react-dom]/cjs/react-dom-server.node.production.min.js:48:37
```

By the way, I'm not using `React.lazy` or `suspense`.

I'm using https://github.com/mik3y/gatsby-starter-basic-bootstra, and have a minimal repro at https://github.com/HiltonGiesenow/gatsby-mgt-test. For completeness, I've tested with an even more simple Starter, with the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I think you add a `null` loader to `@microsoft/mgt-react` package, according to the [Microsoft dependency installation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/toolkit/get-started/use-toolkit-with-react). So:

```
exports.onCreateWebpackConfig = ({ stage, loaders, actions }) => {
    if (stage === "build-html") {
      actions.setWebpackConfig({
        module: {
          rules: [
            {
                test: /@microsoft\/mgt-react/,
                use: loaders.null(),
            },
          ],
        },
      })
    }
  }
```

Note that the testing rule is a regular expression so the value must match a folder name in the `node_modules`, that's why you should escape the slash in `/mgt-react`.

Comment: Nope, that didn't work, now I get:

failed Building static HTML for pages - 5.306s
error Building static HTML failed

> 47 | export class MgtBaseComponent extends LitElement {
     |                                       ^
  48 |     constructor() {
  49 |         super();
  50 |         /**


  WebpackError: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null